# How to update values of a class instance Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am making a text game for fun and can't find a pythonic way to update the player's stats.

I tried variables like h = 100 player = class(h,d,a,w) (health, defense, attack, weight) but then to have the players health change, I have to do this: h -= enemy attack (ea) player = class(h,d,a,w). Which is long and later on brakes when I add in defense and weapons. Variables work but are very long and unstable when I start to do a lot of math with them to make it more interesting. I also looked into class methods but couldn't find a way to pass player some stat as so that it would update.

```py
import random as ran
class Client:
    def __init__(self, health, defense, attack, weight):
        self.health = health
        self.defense = defense
        self.attack = attack
        self.weight = weight
class NPC:
    def __init__(self, health, defense, attack):
        self.health = health
        self.defense = defense
        self.attack = attack

#client inventory
inv = []
#a set of true or false statements to create a loop
alive = True
enemy_alive = False
while alive == True:
    message = input()
    player = Client(100, 0, 0, 0)
    enemy = NPC(100, 0, 20)
    # A way to brake the loop at any time
    if message == "q":
        alive = False
    # Now we need a way to choice a wepon
    if len(inv) == 0:
        if message == "pick up bow":
            print("The bow is now in your inventory.")
            inv.append("Bow")
            # This was my latest atempt to set player attack to the damage of the bow
            player.attack += 25
            combat = True
    if len(inv) > 0 and combat == True:
        if enemy_alive == False:
            print("""A enemy is chargeing at you!
    HP: 100""")
        #We start the fight now that the player has a bow
        enemy_alive = True
        if "Bow" in inv:
#This is where I said to my self what if I could have attack directly effect health so that when the fight loop is broke the players stats stay with them and so that the math is more set and stone
            if minotaur.defense == 0:
               if message == "shoot":
                    hit = ran.randint(0,9)
                    if hit == 9:
                        print("Head Shot")
                        enemy.health = 0
                    if hit <= 4:
                        print("Miss")
                        player.health = player.health-enemy.attack
                        print("HP :"+str(player.health))
                    if hit >= 5:
                        print("HIT!")
                        enemy.health = enemy.health-player.attack
                        print("Enemy HP: "+str(enemy.health))
            if enemy.defense > 0:
            #I made this so I could see if it worked but like above nothing saves correctly
               player.attack = player.attack/minotar.defense
               if message == "shoot":
                    hit = ran.randint(0,9)
                    if hit == 9:
                        print("Head Shot")
                        enemy.health = 0
                    if hit <= 4:
                        print("Miss")
                        player.health = player.health-enemy.attack
                        print("HP :"+str(player.health))
                    if hit > 4:
                        print("HIT!")
                        enemy.health = enemy.health-player.attack
                        print("Enemy HP: "+str(enemy.health))
    if enemy.health <= 0:
        print("The Minotaur died a painful death.")
        minotaur_alive = False
        combat = False
    if player.health <= 0:
        print("You died!")
        alive = False
```

When I execute the code the only thing that doesn't work is the stat updates. I have a debug layer on my real code that allows me to see if the current state of the game so I know for sure that it isn't updating.

Comment: there's so many things wrong with this but my first question is, does it update at any point, like right in the start? or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe consider have every object in the game handle its own behavior: for instance, a `Player` object could have a `Stats` object that gets updated when some event happens.

When this works well with one type of `Player`, you can consider subclassing to modify the behavior; make it harder to kill, of with faster recovery, etc...

Maybe something like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, stats):
        self.name = name
        self.stats = stats

    def get_hit(self, hit_value):
        self.stats.update_health(-hit_value)

    def rest(self):
        self.stats.update_health(10)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Player {self.name}: {self.stats}'


class FastRecoveryPlayer(Player):
    def rest(self):
        self.stats.update_health(20)


class Stats:
    """maintains the Player's stats up to date
    """
    def __init__(self, health=100, defense=100, attack=100):
        self.health = health
        self.defense = defense
        self.attack = attack

    def update_health(self, value):
        self.health += value
        self.health = max(0, self.health)
        self.health = min(100, self.health)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'health: {self.health}, defense: {self.defense}, attack: {self.attack}'


hero = Player('Python King', Stats())
print(hero)

print('the Hero gets hit hard')
hero.get_hit(30)
print(hero)
print('the Hero rests a little bit')
hero.rest()
print(hero)

print()
hero2 = FastRecoveryPlayer('Python Emperor', Stats())
print(hero2)

print('the Hero2 gets hit hard')
hero2.get_hit(30)
print(hero2)
print('the Hero2 rests a little bit')
hero2.rest()
print(hero2)
```

#### output:

```
Player Python King: health: 100, defense: 100, attack: 100
the Hero gets hit hard
Player Python King: health: 70, defense: 100, attack: 100
the Hero rests a little bit
Player Python King: health: 80, defense: 100, attack: 100

Player Python Emperor: health: 100, defense: 100, attack: 100
the Hero2 gets hit hard
Player Python Emperor: health: 70, defense: 100, attack: 100
the Hero2 rests a little bit
Player Python Emperor: health: 90, defense: 100, attack: 100
```

Comment: Thank You! I played around with the way to use the classes a bit and got it to work. I can now freely have the stats be up to date without it breaking.

Comment: How deep down the rabbit hole of abstraction should you go @PythonKing? IDK, but there is an interesting article here: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Answer (score -2):

This is generally related to OO design, I suggest that you have a base class of Character (although not essential) and have Client and NPC inheriting that base class, then have an attack and receive_attack method.

```
class Character():
    def __init__(self, health, defense, damage, weight):
        self.health = health
        self.defense = defense
        self.damage = damage
        self.weight = weight

    def attack(self,target):
        target.receive_attack(self.damage)

    def receive_attack(self,damage):
        self.health -= damage

class Client(Character):
    pass

class NPC(Character):
    pass

class NPC_harder_to_take_down(Character):
    def receive_attack(self,damage):
        self.health -= (damage/2)


me = Client(100,100,100,100)
other = NPC(10,10,10,10)
print(me.health)
>>>100
other.attack(me)
print(me.health)
>>>90
```